# How to avoid cooked pasta soaking up sauce when stored?

Tags: sauce, pasta

I often make up a box of pasta (dried) with some sauce that I make from leftover ingredients for work the next day. The sauce is always either tomato or cream cheese based.

By lunch the next day, the pasta has soaked up a good amount of the excess sauce that was previously filling the base of the box. Aside from storing the pasta and sauce in two separate boxes, is there anything I can do when cooking to avoid this happening? It does not appear to be a problem in supermarket ready meals.

Comment: Do you add oil to the water the pasta boils in?

Comment: mfg, the only effect that oil has when boiling pasta is to in a very very very small way help the water not boil over. It has no other use.

Comment: I don't add oil, as experience and advice from others tells me it does nothing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I plan on storing my pasta in the fridge with the sauce, I take the pasta out of the boiling water and immediately rinse it in cold water. I rinse until the pasta has cooled completely. Make sure to drain it well. Afterwards, I either mix a little sauce in the pasta to help keep it from sticking or just put the sauce on top.
Basically I'm trying to stop the pasta from continuing to "Cook" in the sauce.

Comment: Obvious really, I'm always sticking hot pasta into a box then putting the lid on so it's no wonder it continues cooking in this way. I will do this from now on.

Comment: Never ever rinse pasta! Cardinal sin!

Comment: That may be, but it still works fixes the problem. :)

Comment: What I find works even better than rinsing the pasta is to drain it about 90 seconds before it's done and let it finish cooking with the leftover heat.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod only problem with that is when you misjudge. With the cold water rinse, you halt cooking. It doesn't chill the pasta, it just takes the hot edge off. I rinse it thoroughly in the strainer, then toss it in the strainer to get the water out, and you'll still see plenty of steam and go blind if you wear glasses.

Comment: Rinsing might also take loose starch off that causes gloopyness and sticking.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a little milk (to the creamy pasta) or water before reheating cooked, wet pasta is a good idea because pasta will continue to absorb the moisture in the sauce and 'cook', leaving it dry and overcooked.

You can compensate for this in large quantities (like supermarket meals) by slightly under cooking the pasta and relying on this process of moisture absorption and reheating to finish the cooking process.

Comment: I agree with Christopher -- the only way to achieve "prepared meal" type dishes is to undercook the pasta so it finishes in the sauce.  Of course, if you could easily estimate how much you wanted to save, you could pull that amount before you finished cooking the amount for your current meal, or pull it all, and finish cooking tonight's meal in the sauce, then box up the remainder of the sauce (possibly thinned slightly) and the extra pasta.  You might need to toss a little bit of sauce in with the pasta while it's still warm just to avoid it sticking to itself as it cools.

Comment: I have tried thinning the sauce and it solved the problem of the sauce disappearing, but of course it continued to cook as you said. I'll try the combination of ideas next time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might also be caused by the fact that cooked pasta releases gluten, which thickens your sauce. "Washing" your pasta before putting the sauce in it, as suggested, is a good method, but probably the most simple thing to do in general is to keep your sauce a bit more liquid, and mixing your pasta with a bit of olive oil just before you add your sauce. This way your pasta is somehow "coated" with oil which could prevent a bit the soaking of your sauce.

Comment: I have tried using oil before but didn't like the flavour it added to the dish. Perhaps it wasn't right for the sauce I had at the time.

Comment: Likely starch not gluten. Developed gluten (if it was not developed your pasta would fall apart) is essentially water insoluble.

Answer (score 2):

I've started pulling out the leftovers before finishing cooking a pot of pasta, so that the leftover portion is only partially cooked, rinsing them and letting them cool before adding any sauce.  This works best if you know the portions that work for your family/guests, but is especially handy when trying to enforce measured portion sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I found an extra-yummy recipe for mac and cheese where you put the hot pasta in the casserole, add some butter, mix until it melts, then add the sauce.  It's the first recipe I've found where the sauce didn't soaked into the pasta. I wonder if the butter makes a barrier.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, I'm wondering if maybe putting the sauce on the bottom and the pasta on top might help, hopefully that means it will only be the  absolute bottom of the pasta that soaks up the sauce? Then maybe stirring it together just before reheating..

Comment: Thanks, Sue. Weird to see this again after I posted it 12 years ago! Since then I actually do this, as well as quick cool the pasta before boxing up.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do when I'm making pasta and chicken is to first cook the chicken and add the sauce to the chicken. Then I boil the pasta. When I'm ready to serve, I simply serve my pasta on the bottom with the sauce and meat on top. If u want to cook everything together and have leftovers the next day, you can always cook everything the way I said, put some pasta aside in one Tupperware, chicken and sauce in another container and then cook the rest of the meal together if you like

Comment: The question was explicitly for suggestions *aside from storing ... in two separate boxes*.